# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-dxjZrU/pyproj/ when installing 'geopandas'

Tags: python-2.7, installation, geopandas

Before going to the topic, my computer information:

OS: Debian jessie, Python version: 2.7

I need to install the module "geopandas" for a project i am working on. The problem is that when i tried, i receive the following error:

```
root@debian:~# pip install geopandas
Collecting geopandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0a/0e/8ae74743ed7915ddb7d70cc8dfa8fc0b9b9cc81205c6e288a01915a46192/geopandas-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyproj (from geopandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/29/72/5c1888c4948a0c7b736d10e0f0f69966e7c0874a660222ed0a2c2c6daa9f/pyproj-1.9.5.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    unable to execute 'i586-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory
    using bundled proj4..
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-dxjZrU/pyproj/setup.py", line 72, in <module>
        objects = cc.compile(['nad2bin.c', 'src/pj_malloc.c'])
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
        self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 122, in _compile
        raise CompileError, msg
    distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'i586-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-dxjZrU/pyproj/
```

I also looked other questions in this website about similiar problems, most of people recommend to update the setuptools, i have done that and still doesn't work, here the prove:

```
root@debian:~# pip install --upgrade setuptools
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (39.2.0)
```

If anyone could help me with that i will be really happy

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Debian 8 Jessie, 32bit

> 'i586-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory

```
# apt install g++ gfortran python-all-dev python-numpy libgdal-dev libgeos-dev python-matplotlib


# pip install geopandas
.
.
  Running setup.py install for munch

Successfully installed geopandas shapely pandas fiona descartes pyproj python-dateutil numpy cligj click-plugins munch enum34 click
Cleaning up...
```